# How would I make a program that only prints to lines in a file after it reads a "+" sign in the file

Tags: ruby, file

I need my program to store a lot of login information for different users. I can not get it, however, when it is writing, to only write to the lines after the "+" sign.

So, I need it to skip until it see's the plus sign in the file, then, on the next three lines, put data in the file, then on the fourth line put the plus sign, and remove it from it's original location.

I have tried absolutely everything that involves that part of the code.

It needs to work like this

Run #1

```
bla
bla
bla
+
```

Run #2

```
bla
bla
bla

bla
bla
bla
+


I want this thing to finally work.
```

Comment: Take a stab at solving this problem. Hint: `$stdin.each_line do |line|` and go from there.

Comment: I assume that `"+\n"` is not necessarily the last line of the file. Correct? Is it a particularly large file? The usual way is to open an (empty) "output" file for writing, and read the "input" file a line at a time. If the line does not contain the plus sign, write it to the output file; if is does contain the plus sign, write the 3 specified lines and a line with the plus sign to the output file and then carry on as before. After the last line of the input file has been read and processed, close both files, delete the input file and rename the output file to the name of the input file.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I have no idea if what you're showing is supposed to be input to your program, output on the console, file contents, or what...

Comment: Members are here to help, but their enthusiasm wanes when askers do not respond to comments that ask for clarification of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
new_contents = ''
File.open('file_name').each do |line|
  new_contents << line unless /^\+/.match line
  ## Handle the plus sign here. Add whatever content you want
end
File.write('file_name', new_contents)
```

Comment: If you're going to read the entire file into memory, you might consider just gulping it into a string, replacing ''+'` with the desired string and writing the result to a new file: `File.write(outfile, File.read(infile).sub('+', ...))`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that would work, but assumes that there can not be plus signs mixed in with the normal content, and only allows one plus sign.

Doing it procedurally allows him to keep a separate counter or something if he needs to know how many plus signs he's processed.

Comment: I have ran into one error. I need it to skip all lines until the plus sign, then, starting at the line after the plus sign, write three lines, then on the next replace the plus sign